# Why split function doesn't return a null at the first of this string?

Tags: c#

I have implemented a code in C#, I pass this string `//Comment` to function. why function returns true?

```
bool function(string buf){    
    // split buffer from "//" and avoid from comment
    string[] lineSplit = buf.Split(new string[] { "//" },     StringSplitOptions.None);
    // split part of string from space and tab, and put into buffer
    if (lineSplit[0] != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: if `//comment` break, lineSplit is `null` and `comment`, so this condition is false!

Comment: Btw, at the moment you split with a single  \ , not with a double. Maybe your intend is  @"\\"

Comment: @MasoudHosseini No, `lineSplit` isn't `null`.  It's a 2 element array that has an empty string and `comment` in it.

Comment: Such questions are easily resolved with a debugger. `split(..., SplitStringOptions.None)` return empty strings, not `null`s, for empty elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string split method will have the first element as `String.Empty` if your delimiter appears at the beginning of the string. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You would want to change your if statement that is checking null to something like this:

```
bool function(string buf){    
    // split buffer from "//" and avoid from comment
    string[] lineSplit = buf.Split(new string[] { "//" },     StringSplitOptions.None);
    // split part of string from space and tab, and put into buffer
    if (lineSplit[0] != string.Empty)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It will *never* be `null`.  There's no reason to check it against `null`.  It's either empty, or it has values.  Those are the only options.

Comment: @Servy that is true, but sadly there is no `string.IsEmpty()` and I prefer the whole `!string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to `string != string.Empty` also I missed the exclamation mark to make it a not. Time to edit!

Comment: @DavidWatts If you want to know if a string isn't empty, you simply  need to compare it to an empty string.  Doing other checks implies that those other values may in fact be relevant.

Comment: @DavidWatts But the `IsNullOrEmpty` seems to put too much emphasis on the "IsNull" part. And if you want to check against an empty string, it's best to just check the `.Length` (or you can compare against an empty string, but that's not so efficient)

Comment: @Servy you are right, it could be a little misleading. Editing answer!

Comment: @MatthewWatson The cost of comparing a string to the empty string is going to be *very* small, and it will be *very* similar to comparing the length to zero.  The chances of that being a performance bottleneck in your code are basically zero.

Comment: @Servy Agreed, but I actually find it more readable to do `if (lineSplit[0].Length > 0)` rather than `if (lineSplit[0] != string.Empty)` but it really is a matter of personal preference. [Unless you have a certain Code Analysis rule turned on, of course](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279.aspx) "CA1820: Test for empty strings using string length" ;)

Comment: (Contn:) As CA1820 says: "Comparing strings using the String.Length property or the String.IsNullOrEmpty method is significantly faster than using Equals. This is because Equals executes significantly more MSIL instructions than either IsNullOrEmpty or the number of instructions executed to retrieve the Length property value and compare it to zero."

Answer (score 2):

you should be checking for " "  or string.Empty

```
public bool function(string buf)
    { 

        string[] lineSplit = buf.Split(new string[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

      if (lineSplit[0] != string.Empty)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```